# How to set backgroundcolor and border for each array element using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, django

I am trying to set separate background and border for each element in the array using JavaScript something [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1S1ad.png). Until now what I have done [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRCH5.png)is below. As I add a new element to the array, it will stretch the background.

```js
let skills = [];

function displayname() {
  console.log(document.getElementById("namehere").value);
  x = document.getElementById("namehere").value;
  skills.push(x);
  console.log(skills)
  document.getElementById("skill-set").innerHTML = skills
  document.getElementById("skill-set").style.border = "1px solid blue";
  document.getElementById("skill-set").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
  document.getElementById("skill-set").style.padding = "5px";
  document.getElementById("skill-set").style.display = "inline-block";
  document.getElementById('namehere').value = " ";
}
```

```html
<label>Enter the skills: </label><br>
<input type=t ext id="namehere" onchange="displayname()">
<div id="skill-set"></div>
```

Comment: have you tried to loop the elements to set the css?

Answer (score 4):

Why not create div ? like:

```js
function displayname(el) {
  var skilldiv = document.getElementById("skill-set");
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.classList.add("mystyle");
  var content = document.createTextNode(el.value); 
  div.appendChild(content);  
  skilldiv.appendChild(div);
}
```

```css
#skill-set div {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<label>Enter the skills: </label><br>
<input type="text" id="namehere" onchange="displayname(this)">
<div id="skill-set"></div>
```

Everytime you set new skill, function will create a new div.

Edit from your comment:

```js
function displayname(el) {
  var skilldiv = document.getElementById("skill-set");
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.classList.add("mystyle");
  var content = document.createTextNode(el.value); 
  div.appendChild(content);  
  skilldiv.appendChild(div);
}
```

```css
#skill-set div {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<label>Enter the skills: </label><br>
<select name="namehere" id="namehere" onChange="displayname(this)">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="java">Java</option>
  <option value="php">PHP</option>
  <option value="html">Html</option>

</select>
<div id="skill-set"></div>
```

Comment: How can i select a element from a list? I need something like array ['Java', 'Python','HTML', 'Css',].. when I focus on Input type I should get a list of item to be selected.How can I achieve this?

Comment: List is from dropdown/select box?

Comment: List is Dropdown

Comment: can you paste your html(dropdown) in your question  so i can change it on my answer?

Comment: I have not implemented dropdown yet as I was exploring the first step..

Comment: i add select see if is ok for you

Comment: Select statement allows me to select value from the list and prevent me from pass value to it. I need something like datalist but it should get the list from database

Comment: _prevent me from pass value to it_ why ? you can use value for pass the value.. i don't understand the problem :)

Answer (score 2):

To achieve what you describe you should separate each tag in to its own element. That way the background and border apply to that specific tag only.

In addition you should set the styling rules through CSS directly, not on each element at the point you create them. Try this:

```js
let skills = [];
let skillSet = document.querySelector('#skill-set');

document.querySelector('#namehere').addEventListener('change', e => {
  skills.push(e.target.value);
  e.target.value = '';
  displaySkills();
});

let displaySkills = () => {
  let tags = skills.map(skill => `<span>${skill}</span>`).join('');
  skillSet.innerHTML = tags;
}
```

```css
#skill-set span {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<label>Enter the skills: </label><br>
<input type="text" id="namehere" />
<div id="skill-set"></div>
```

Comment: How can i select a element  from a list?

Comment: Assuming by 'list' you mean an array, then by its index, eg. `foo[0]`. If that's not what you meant, I'll need more information

Comment: Ah, you mean the tags you're creating? Hook an event handler to them.

Comment: I need something like array  ['Java', 'Python','HTML', 'Css',].. when I focus on Input type I should get a  list of item to be selected. hope i'm clear

Comment: That's called an autocomplete control. I'd suggest starting a new question about it if you want to build your own

Answer (score 2):

Instead of appending the text inside the same div you could create a new element and append that instead. This way the styling can be used for each individual item.

By using a CSS class instead of JS we don't have the set the styling each time but we can just append the classname.

```js
const skills = [];

const skillSet = document.getElementById("skill-set");
const input = document.getElementById("namehere");

function displayname() {
  const skill = document.createElement("span");
  skill.textContent = input.value;
  skill.classList.add("box");
  
  skillSet.appendChild(skill);
  
  skills.push(input.value);
  
  input.value = " ";
}
```

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background: yellow;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px 5px 0 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<label>Enter the skills: </label><br>
<input type=t ext id="namehere" onchange="displayname()">
<div id="skill-set"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting the array as the `innerHTML` value, try to loop over the `skills` array and create an element for each skill. This way you can add classes or other properties to identify these elements and style them through CSS.

```js
let skills = [];
const nameHere = document.getElementById("namehere");
const skillSet = document.getElementById("skill-set")

function displayname() {
  let skill = nameHere.value;
  skills.push(skill);
  while(skillSet.firstElementChild) {
    skillSet.firstElementChild.remove();
  }
  skills.forEach(function(skill) {
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.classList.add('skill');
    div.textContent = skill;
    skillSet.append(div);
  });
  nameHere.value = '';
}
```

```css
#skill-set {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.skill {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 5px;
}

.skill + .skill {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<label>Enter the skills: </label><br>
<input type=t ext id="namehere" onchange="displayname()">
<div id="skill-set"></div>
```

Comment: How can i select a element from a list? I need something like array ['Java', 'Python','HTML', 'Css',].. when I focus on Input type I should get a list of item to be selected.How can I achieve?

Comment: That's autocomplete behavior. You can use the [`<datalist>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist) element or build your own behavior.

Answer (score 1):

### Update

If you want a type-ahead list, you can try the following.

It was adapted from this code: http://jsfiddle.net/bebarr89/tZDAd/

```js
const skills = [ 'Java', 'JavaScript', 'Perl', 'Python', 'HTML', 'CSS' ];
const selectedSkills = new Set();

const autoComplete = document.querySelector('.autocomplete input');
const autoCompleteList = document.querySelector('#autocomplete-list');
const skillSet = document.querySelector('#skill-set');

autoComplete.addEventListener('keyup', dropdownShow);
autoComplete.addEventListener('change', dropdownShow);
autoComplete.addEventListener('focus', dropdownShow);

function addToSkills(skill) {
  const skillItem = document.createElement('div'); // Create element
  skillItem.textContent = skill; // Set element text
  skillItem.classList.add('skill');
  skillSet.appendChild(skillItem);
}

function dropdownHide() {
  autoCompleteList.innerHTML = '';
  autoCompleteList.style.display = 'none';
}

function dropdownShow() {
  if (!autoComplete.value) {
    dropdownHide();
    return;
  }
  const expression = new RegExp('^' + autoComplete.value, 'i');
  const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  
  skills.sort()
    .filter(skill =>
      !selectedSkills.has(skill) && expression.test(skill))
    .forEach(skill => {
      var item = document.createElement('div');
      item.classList.add('autocomplete-item');
      item.innerText = skill;
      item.addEventListener('click', selectAndClose);
      fragment.appendChild(item);
    });
  if (fragment.children.length) {
    autoCompleteList.innerHTML = '';
    autoCompleteList.style.display = 'block';
    autoCompleteList.appendChild(fragment);
    return;
  }
  dropdownHide();
}

function selectAndClose(e) {
  const skill = this.textContent;
  autoComplete.value = skill;
  if (!selectedSkills.has(skill)) {
    selectedSkills.add(skill);
    autoComplete.value = ''; // Clear?
    addToSkills(skill);
  }
  dropdownHide();
}
```

```css
#skill-set {
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}

.skill {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.autocomplete {
  display: inline-block;
}

.autocomplete input {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  outline: none;
  margin: 0;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0.25em;
}

#autocomplete-list {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  border-top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 93px;
  background: #fff;
}

.autocomplete input, #autocomplete-list {
  width: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#autocomplete-list .autocomplete-item {
  padding: 0.25em;
}

#autocomplete-list .autocomplete-item:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background: #f6f6f6;
}

#autocomplete-list .autocomplete-item:hover {
  background: #e5e5e5;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<form name="skills" onsubmit="return false">
  <label>Choose skill(s):</label>
  <div class="autocomplete">
    <input type="text" name="skill" autocomplete="off">
    <div id="autocomplete-list" style="display:none"></div>
  </div>
</form>
<div id="skill-set"></div>
```

---

You need to create a new element for each skill you add. Do not modify the inner HTML of the entire div.

```js
const input = document.getElementById('namehere');
const skillSet = document.getElementById('skill-set');
const skills = [];

function displayname() {
  const value = input.value.trim(); // Capture value
  input.value = ''; // Reset field
  skills.push(value); // Add text to skill list
  const skillItem = document.createElement('div'); // Create element
  skillItem.textContent = value; // Set element text
  skillItem.classList.add('skill');
  // Apply style
  Object.assign(skillItem.style, { 
    border : "1px solid blue",
    backgroundColor : "yellow",
    padding : "5px",
    display : "inline-block"
  });
  skillSet.appendChild(skillItem);
}
```

```css
#skill-set {
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}

.skill {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<label>Enter the skills: </label><br>
<input type="text" id="namehere" onchange="displayname()">
<div id="skill-set"></div>
```

Also, instead of applying style via JavaScript, just add a class with CSS.

Comment: How can i select a element from a list? I need something like array ['Java', 'Python','HTML', 'Css',].. when I focus on Input type I should get a list of item to be selected.How can I achieve?

Comment: @Mohammedzuhair Isn't that a `<select>` input?

Comment: No I need to pass it from database?

Comment: @Mohammedzuhair See the dynamic example in the edit.